# Mac os shell script cd folder with spaces not working

Tags: bash, macos, shell, escaping

Before I begin, please don't bite my head off I know this question has been asked many times here and in other forums, but I can't get this simple shell script to work.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

DEST=“/Volumes/Ext\ 1TB/Google\ Drive/Backup\ Ralph/mac”

echo dest is $DEST
cd $DEST
```

and this is my output:

```
bash -x gdrive.sh 
+ DEST='“/Volumes/Ext 1TB/Google Drive/Backup Ralph/mac”'
+ echo dest is $'?\200\234/Volumes/Ext' 1TB/Google Drive/Backup $'Ralph/mac?\200\235'
dest is “/Volumes/Ext 1TB/Google Drive/Backup Ralph/mac”
+ cd $'?\200\234/Volumes/Ext' 1TB/Google Drive/Backup $'Ralph/mac?\200\235'
gdrive.sh: line 6: cd: “/Volumes/Ext: No such file or directory
```

I tried lots of combinations like single or double quotes or escape wit a backslash or or double quote and escape with a backslash

if I put double quotes around my variable the output give me some numbers as you see in my example.

Does someone knows what the right usage and combination of quotes of escaping is?

I hope someone can help

Regards,

Ralph

Comment: The double-quotes are not plain double-quotes, but special characters. Here it is fixed: `"/Volumes/Ext\ 1TB/Google\ Drive/Backup\ Ralph/mac"`. Btw you don't need to escape the embedded spaces with \, this would also work just fine: `"/Volumes/Ext 1TB/Google Drive/Backup Ralph/mac"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do:

```
DEST="/Volumes/Ext 1TB/Google Drive/Backup Ralph/mac"

cd "$DEST"
```

you need the quotes in the `cd` line as the value of `$DEST` is simply inserted into the command line and without them that produces 4 arguments to `cd`:

```
cd $DEST
```

=>

```
cd /Volumes/Ext 1TB/Google Drive/Backup Ralph/mac
```

HTH

P.S. I assume the curly quotes, “”, in your question are just an auto-correct typo and you know to use straight quotes, ""

Comment: That's it! it works those curly quotes, was not a typo, I edit the bash file in the default text editor of mac os... this text editor converts normal quotes to curly quotes. Never thought of the curly quotes Thanks CRD. That won't happen again, I installed sublime text 3 now, I'll use the text editor for typing letters from now on :-)